# Why can't I add a mail-enabled security group as member inside Office 365 group

Tags: office-365, office-365-groups

I have created a mail-enabled security group inside our Office 365 tenant. and i created an Office 365 group, but I am unable to add the mail-enabled security group inside the Office 365 group as member or as owner. Any advice?

Comment: Are you getting any error while adding?

Comment: *Mail-enabled security groups can be added to a team.* Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/compare-groups?view=o365-worldwide#mail-enabled-security-groups

Comment: @GaneshSanap the group will not be auto-completed so i can not added?

Comment: I just tried it from admin center & observed same behavior.

Comment: @GaneshSanap so how we can add the mail enalbed inside office 365 group other than UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M365 Groups do not support nesting of any other group. However, there is a newer preview feature which lets you do this:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/create-quot-nested-quot-groups-with-azure-ad-dynamic-groups/ba-p/3118024

Comment: thanks but what you mean by 'do not support testing ...'